print option `n = Inf` now leads to an error "invalid 'na.print' specification"
As of today, using the n parameter in the print function does not work anymore.
I guess it has to do with my update to R Version 4.1.1, but couldn't find anything about it in the release notes.
Worked before, but does not work anymore:
mtcars |>
  print(n = Inf)

Any idea, how I can use such a print command to define the number of rows to be printed? This is important when displaying tibbles, which, by default, only display a few rows.
UPDATE: while my main goal is to define the displayed rows in tibbles, the print(n = Inf) previously also worked with normal data frames (which it doesn't anymore).

mtcars data is not a tbl. Convert it to a tibble first. mtcars |> tibble() |> print(n=Inf)

True, but the print argument also worked for data frames before.

Not if you supply Inf for the "na.print" argument. Remember, R allows short-cut argument names. n = na.print.

Are you sure it used to work with data frames?  See https://tio.run/##K/r/P0ivLLWoODM/T6@4pCgzL52rAEiWaOSWJCcWFeso5CnYKnjmpWn@/w8A where it doesn't work in an R release almost 6 years ago.

When you use print, you are assuming you want the print.tbl method, but mtcars is not a tbl, so R is trying to use the default print method, which invokes print.data.frame, which invokes print.default, which has an na.print argument and you can't specify Inf for that argument.
So, convert your data frame to a tbl first:
mtcars |>
  tibble() |>
  print(n=Inf)


# A tibble: 32 x 11
     mpg   cyl  disp    hp  drat    wt  qsec    vs    am  gear  carb
   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
 1  21       6  160    110  3.9   2.62  16.5     0     1     4     4
 2  21       6  160    110  3.9   2.88  17.0     0     1     4     4
 3  22.8     4  108     93  3.85  2.32  18.6     1     1     4     1
 4  21.4     6  258    110  3.08  3.22  19.4     1     0     3     1
 5  18.7     8  360    175  3.15  3.44  17.0     0     0     3     2
 6  18.1     6  225    105  2.76  3.46  20.2     1     0     3     1
 7  14.3     8  360    245  3.21  3.57  15.8     0     0     3     4
 8  24.4     4  147.    62  3.69  3.19  20       1     0     4     2
 9  22.8     4  141.    95  3.92  3.15  22.9     1     0     4     2
10  19.2     6  168.   123  3.92  3.44  18.3     1     0     4     4

Edit: I forgot to mention that since R allows abbreviated argument names, n will be assumed to be na.print.

Thanks for the explanation, which makes sense. One question though: why did it work until now? I.e. was there a particular change in R that now leads to the error? The print(n = Inf) argument did work on data frames before.

Sorry - I don't know. I'd have to install an old R version to find out why. Or scroll through the R news, which may take a long time. I can have a quick look... someone else may know off hand...

I also went through the release notes, but noting suspicious there (which does not mean there wasn't a change, just that I probably don't immediately understand where the change might be hidden).

I went back to R 4.0.2 and it doesn't work. Do you know which version it worked?

ok, I also tried with an older version, where it doesn't work. I'm pretty confused now, because my code did work last week, and doesn't now. I'll investigate. One explanation might be that the underlying data changed and for whatever reason it is now still a data.frame, whereas before it was a tibble.
